# Show Instantly taskbar when auto-hide on - windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have the Windows 7 taskbar set to autohide.

Is it possible to reduce the delay of the taskbar when i want to see it again? Show it instantly, like when we reduce the time to see the previews there...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `My Computer`;
2. Right click the `My Computer` icon;
3. Properties;
4. System properties;
5. Advanced;
6. Performance;
7. Settings;
8. Uncheck/check (as applicable) "Fade or slide menus into view";
9. Hit **Apply and OK**.

Alternatively on Windows 10:

1. Search for "View advanced system settings" in the Start or Settings menu.
2. Go to step 6 above.

Comment: Under Windows 8 Step 4 is "Change Settings" on the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, even without animation there's still a ~50-100ms delay before the taskbar reveals itself. Supremely annoying.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way to speed up the process is to completely disable the Aero animations.

To do this:

1. Open your start-menu and type in "System" and select the option under the "Control Panel" section.
2. Click on "Advanced system settings" in the left-pane.
3. Click on the "Advanced" tab.
4. Click on "Settings" in the performance sub-section.
5. Uncheck "Animations in taskbar and Start Menu" and possibly (not sure if it is necessary) "Animate controls and elements inside windows".

Good luck!

Comment: Certainly not working for me. I don't have to restart or log out or the such, right? Are you sure you don't mean to untick `Fade or Slide Menus into View` option?

Comment: Not working for me either. `Fade or slide menus into view` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to press the Windows key - that'll pop out the taskbar instantly.

There doesn't seem to be any registry hack or setting that can be used to remove the delay, however, using a 3rd party app called [Taskbar Activate](http://pmdevigne.free.fr/programmes_e.html#ActiveTache) - you can remove the delay completely from within the settings.

I found a very slight reduction in display time, myself - YMMV. This utility was designed to in fact *increase* the delay time so the bar wouldn't pop up each time a user brought the mouse close to the edge of the screen. It's <strike>freeware</strike> "emailware" and there's a portable / no-install version available too.